# How to insert text after a certain complex string in a file using SED

Tags: sed

I want to add new line in a html file by using sed command

The line I  want to add is

```
<link href="https://newvalue.css" rel="test1" id="test2">
```

After

```
<link href="test.css" rel="test1" id="test2">
```

in a html file.

Can anyone help ?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please do add samples of your input and expected output along with your efforts in your question(which is highly encouraged on SO), thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use sed and a for append and so:

```
sed -i '/<link href="test.css" rel="test1" id="test2">/a<link href="https://newvalue.css" rel="test1" id="test2">' file
```

Search for the line by using /.../ and then use a for append followed by the string to add.

Comment: Thanks @raman Sailopal 

but Got error  sed: -e expression #1, char : extra characters after command

Comment: Could be your version of sed.